# Split String into groups with specific length

Tags: string, swift, split, divide

How can I split the given `String` in Swift into groups with given length, reading from right to left?

For example, I have string `123456789` and group length of 3. The the string should be divided into 3 groups: `123`, `456`, `789`. String `1234567` will be divided into `1`, `234`, `567`

So, can you write some nice code in Swift:

```
func splitedString(string: String, length: Int) -> [String] {

}
```

BTW tried function `split()`, but as I understand it works only with finding some symbol

Comment: What is the goal and what are the constraints? Are you trying to format number representations, ex: "10000" becomes "10 000", by any chance?

Comment: @EricD. No, `NSNumberFormatter` is not my case. I just want to know, can I realize this functionality with `split()` function or some other nice solution.

Comment: Note exactly the same (because the *last* chunk is truncated, not the first as in your example), but might server as a starting point: stackoverflow.com/a/28560013/1187415.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to add my entry to this very crowded contest ([SwiftStub](http://swiftstub.com/818843471/?v=beta)):

```
func splitedString(string: String, length: Int) -> [String] {
    var result = [String]()

    for var i = 0; i < string.characters.count; i += length {
        let endIndex = string.endIndex.advancedBy(-i)
        let startIndex = endIndex.advancedBy(-length, limit: string.startIndex)
        result.append(string[startIndex..<endIndex])
    }

    return result.reverse()
}
```

---

Or if you are feeling functional-y:

```
func splitedString2(string: String, length: Int) -> [String] {
    return 0.stride(to: string.characters.count, by: length)
        .reverse()
        .map {
            i -> String in
            let endIndex = string.endIndex.advancedBy(-i)
            let startIndex = endIndex.advancedBy(-length, limit: string.startIndex)
            return string[startIndex..<endIndex]
        }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 4**

I adapted the [answer given by cafedeichi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46883426/2805570) to operate either left-to-right or right-to-left depending on a function parameter, so it's more versatile.

```
extension String {
    /// Splits a string into groups of `every` n characters, grouping from left-to-right by default. If `backwards` is true, right-to-left.
    public func split(every: Int, backwards: Bool = false) -> [String] {
        var result = [String]()

        for i in stride(from: 0, to: self.count, by: every) {
            switch backwards {
            case true:
                let endIndex = self.index(self.endIndex, offsetBy: -i)
                let startIndex = self.index(endIndex, offsetBy: -every, limitedBy: self.startIndex) ?? self.startIndex
                result.insert(String(self[startIndex..<endIndex]), at: 0)
            case false:
                let startIndex = self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: i)
                let endIndex = self.index(startIndex, offsetBy: every, limitedBy: self.endIndex) ?? self.endIndex
                result.append(String(self[startIndex..<endIndex]))
            }
        }

        return result
    }
}
```

Example:

```
"abcde".split(every: 2)                     // ["ab", "cd", "e"]
"abcde".split(every: 2, backwards: true)    // ["a", "bc", "de"]

"abcde".split(every: 4)                     // ["abcd", "e"]
"abcde".split(every: 4, backwards: true)    // ["a", "bcde"]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
func split(every length:Int) -> [Substring] {
    guard length > 0 && length < count else { return [suffix(from:startIndex)] }

    return (0 ... (count - 1) / length).map { dropFirst($0 * length).prefix(length) }
}

func split(backwardsEvery length:Int) -> [Substring] {
    guard length > 0 && length < count else { return [suffix(from:startIndex)] }

    return (0 ... (count - 1) / length).map { dropLast($0 * length).suffix(length) }.reversed()
}
```

Tests:

```
    XCTAssertEqual("0123456789".split(every:2), ["01", "23", "45", "67", "89"])
    XCTAssertEqual("0123456789".split(backwardsEvery:2), ["01", "23", "45", "67", "89"])
    XCTAssertEqual("0123456789".split(every:3), ["012", "345", "678", "9"])
    XCTAssertEqual("0123456789".split(backwardsEvery:3), ["0", "123", "456", "789"])
    XCTAssertEqual("0123456789".split(every:4), ["0123", "4567", "89"])
    XCTAssertEqual("0123456789".split(backwardsEvery:4), ["01", "2345", "6789"])
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with off the top of my head. I bet there is a better way of doing it so I'd encourage you to keep trying.

```
func splitedString(string: String, length: Int) -> [String] {
    var groups = [String]()
    var currentGroup = ""
    for index in string.startIndex..<string.endIndex {
        currentGroup.append(string[index])
        if currentGroup.characters.count == 3 {
            groups.append(currentGroup)
            currentGroup = ""
        }
    }

    if currentGroup.characters.count > 0 {
        groups.append(currentGroup)
    }

    return groups
}
```

Here were my tests

```
let firstString = "123456789"
let groups = splitedString(firstString, length: 3)
// Returned ["123", "456", "789"]

let secondString = "1234567"
let moreGroups = splitedString(secondString, length: 3)
// Returned ["123", "456", "7"]
```

Comment: This truncates the last chunk, not the first as in the example in the question.

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to use `split()` function?

Comment: I've been trying to use that but with no luck currently.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version using NSRegularExpressions

```
func splitedString(string: String, length: Int) -> [String] {
    var groups = [String]()
    let regexString = "(\\d{1,\(length)})"
    do {
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regexString, options: .CaseInsensitive)
        let matches = regex.matchesInString(string, options: .ReportCompletion, range: NSMakeRange(0, string.characters.count))
        let nsstring = string as NSString
        matches.forEach {
            let group = nsstring.substringWithRange($0.range) as String
            groups.append(group)
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Bad Regex Format = \(error)")
    }

    return groups
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an another version with Functional Programming.

```
extension String{
    func splitedString(length: Int) -> [String]{
        guard length > 0 else { return [] }
        let range = 0..<((characters.count+length-1)/length)
        let indices = range.map{ length*$0..<min(length*($0+1),characters.count) }
        return indices
                .map{ characters.reverse()[$0.startIndex..<$0.endIndex] }
                .map( String.init )
    }
}

"1234567890".splitedString(3)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4**

I think the extension method is more useful.

```
extension String{

    public func splitedBy(length: Int) -> [String] {

        var result = [String]()

        for i in stride(from: 0, to: self.characters.count, by: length) {
            let endIndex = self.index(self.endIndex, offsetBy: -i)
            let startIndex = self.index(endIndex, offsetBy: -length, limitedBy: self.startIndex) ?? self.startIndex
            result.append(String(self[startIndex..<endIndex]))
        }

        return result.reversed()

    }

}
```

the example of use:

```
Swift.debugPrint("123456789".splitedBy(length: 4))
// Returned ["1", "2345", "6789"]
```

Comment: This will unnecessarily offset all the way from the end of the string on every iteration. You should also use the count property of the string itself

Answer (score 0):

I made something like this, couldn't create anything better looking, but its result matches the question:

```
func splitedString(string: String, lenght: Int) -> [String] {
    var result = [String](), count = 0, line = ""
    for c in string.characters.reverse() {
        count++; line.append(c)
        if count == lenght {count = 0; result.append(String(line.characters.reverse())); line = ""}
    }
    if !line.isEmpty {result.append(String(line.characters.reverse()))}
    return result.reverse()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a more elegant solution, but this works:

```
func splitedString(string: String, length: Int) -> [String] {
    let string = Array(string.characters)
    let firstGroupLength = string.count % length
    var result: [String] = []
    var group = ""

    if firstGroupLength > 0 {
        for i in 0..<firstGroupLength {
            group.append(string[i])
        }
        result.append(String(group))
        group = ""
    }

    for i in firstGroupLength..<string.count {
        group.append(string[i])
        if group.characters.count == length {
            result.append(group)
            group = ""
        }
    }
    return result
}

splitedString("abcdefg", length: 2) // ["a", "bc", "de", "fg"]
splitedString("1234567", length: 3) // ["1", "234", "567"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using substrings:

```
func splitStringByIntervals(str: String, interval: Int) -> [String] {

   let st = String(str.characters.reverse())
   let length = st.characters.count  
   var groups = [String]()

   for (var i = 0; i < length; i += interval) {
       groups.append((st as NSString).substringWithRange(NSRange(location: i, length: min(interval, length - i))))
   }

   return groups.map{ String($0.characters.reverse())}.reverse()
}
```

The output for :

```
for element in splitStringByIntervals("1234567", interval: 3) {
   print(element)
}
```

is:

```
1
234
567
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this extention:

```
extension String {
    func split(by length: Int) -> [String] {
        var startIndex = self.startIndex
        var results = [Substring]()

        while startIndex < self.endIndex {
            let endIndex = self.index(startIndex, offsetBy: length, limitedBy: self.endIndex) ?? self.endIndex
            results.append(self[startIndex..<endIndex])
            startIndex = endIndex
        }

        return results.map { String($0) }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var array: [String] = []
let stringData = "Hello World"
 
array = stringData.split(by: 3)
```