# split string and integer in specific length python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, split, python-3.6

Good day Everybody, I have question, is there away to split the data into fixed length ?

suppose

```
data=2220591972004161833372381965973430564161832220599125418620936367891254212825967504230783108294828632042934883049336591444611742626636047927395221895991254390547243063380503905471**64**
```

I want to split into 3 part like:

```
d1=222059197200416183337238196597343056416183222059912541862093636789125421282596750423078310829482863204293488304933659144461174262663604792739522189599125439054724306338

d3=050390 >>>> length is 6

d4=5471 >>>>> length is 4
```

Where the last **2 digits** of `data is 64` are used to determine the **length of d3 and d4**.

I have seen many example of split function as list and so on but none of these is what i look for such like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33305157/split-string-into-groups-with-specific-length) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36575098/python-split-string-in-a-certain-length) there is one program written in c++ i want same like in python [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16709314/split-string-using-loop-to-specific-length-sub-units)

another example for string data split data into to parts same way, last one digit is a size of x2

```
data2=cc32b326560de95d0fba47b5ad9072418f15caca4c39c2fe4db7003f4b8f81a79
x=cc32b326560de95d0fba47b5ad9072418f15caca4c39c2fe4db7003
x1=f4b8f81a7 >>>>length is 9
```

i'm using `python 3.6` spyder. thanks all

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're asking here. You say you want to split strings by specific lengths, but you have given two sets of strings with different lengths as examples

Comment: yes, i want to split the string by specific length , i have mention two example data and data1 both different, the first example data need to divide into 3 parts as i describe into d1 and d3 and d4 , the length of d3 6 and the length of d4 is 4, its already mention last 2 digit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `data` is a string, you could use the following function, which takes `data` and an integer `n`, which tells how many characters from the end of the string to use.

```
def split(data, n):
    indices = list(int(x) for x in data[-n:])
    data = data[:-n]
    rv = []
    for i in indices[::-1]:
        rv.append(data[-i:])
        data=data[:-i]
    rv.append(data)
    return rv[::-1]
```

**Usage:**

```
>>> split(data, 2)
['222059197200416183337238196597343056416183222059912541862093636789125421282596750423078310829482863204293488304933659144461174262663604792739522189599125439054724306338',
 '050390',
 '5471']
>>> split(data2, 1)
['cc32b326560de95d0fba47b5ad9072418f15caca4c39c2fe4db7003', 'f4b8f81a7']
```

If you want `n` to always be 2, just edit the function as follows:

```
def split(data):
    indices = list(int(x) for x in data[-2:])
    data = data[:-2]
    rv = []
    for i in indices[::-1]:
        rv.append(data[-i:])
        data=data[:-i]
    rv.append(data)
    return rv[::-1]
```

To assign to variables, then, you could use

```
>>> d1, d2, d3 = split(data)
>>> d1
'222059197200416183337238196597343056416183222059912541862093636789125421282596750423078310829482863204293488304933659144461174262663604792739522189599125439054724306338'
>>> d2
'050390'
>>> d3
'5471'
```

Comment: not working and give TypeError: 'long' object has no attribute '__getitem__' , but still i need to divide into 3 part, the value of n read it from the data it self , its last 2 digit is the length

Comment: @honey as I said, this assumes that `data` is a string. Try with `split(str(data), 2)`

Comment: @honey How do you decide the value of `n`? You have two examples in your post, one splits into two parts, one splits into three parts.

Answer (score 1):

```
data=222059197200416183337238196597343056416183222059912541862093636789125421282596750423078310829482863204293488304933659144461174262663604792739522189599125439054724306338050390547164

data = str(data)
length_d3 = int(data[-1])
length_d2 = int(data[-2])
data = data[0:-2]

d1 = int(data[0:-(length_d3+length_d2)])
d2 = int(data[-(length_d3+length_d2):-length_d3])
d3 = int(data[-length_d3:])

print(d1)
print(d2)
print(d3)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the specific lengths you have provided, this will split them properly

```py
data="222059197200416183337238196597343056416183222059912541862093636789125421282596750423078310829482863204293488304933659144461174262663604792739522189599125439054724306338050390547164"
d1 = data[:-12] # From the start to 12 characters from the end
d3 = data[-12:-6] # From 12 characters from the end to 6 characters from the end
d4 = data[-6:-2] # From 6 characters from the end to 2 characters from the end
```

Comment: how to make the specific length is dynamic not static, because the data will be have different size, i want the size length take it from last 2 digit of original data

Comment: If what you want is to (ignoring the last two characters) have d4 be the last 4 characters, d3 be the last 6 characters before that, and d1 to be the rest, then this will work for all lengths of data (as long as they’re at least 12 long)

Comment: ya sir, the point of last 2 digits is to specify the length of d3 and d4, because the d1 is dynamic and the length will change so it cant be 12 all time , thank you sir, your code is work as you said with fixed size of d1, but if we need to make it as dynamic size? where the last 2 digit from the string take it automatically to define the size of d3 and d4 and the remaining is d1. what change we can do?